# Formatting time on a plot in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code and was wondering how I could format the time to read in a 12 hr format. e.g. 0:00, 3:30, 10:00 etc. as of now the y axis reads 00:00:00, 00:01:00, 00:02:00 and so on. The data in the csv was formatted like this, 0:00, 1:00,2:00 etc.

How could I go about formatting the y axis to the format I need to?

Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=None)

ints = data[data[1]=='INT']
exts = data[data[1]=='EXT']

int_times = [datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')) 
             for t in ints[4]]
ext_times = [datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')) 
             for t in exts[4]]
int_dist = [d for d in ints[3]]
ext_dist = [d for d in exts[3]]

axis_times = ['0:00','01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00','06:00',
              '07:00','08:00','09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(int_dist, int_times, c='red', s=50)
ax.scatter(ext_dist, ext_times, c='blue', s=50)

plt.yticks( axis_times, size='small')

plt.legend(['INT', 'EXT'], loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Time')

plt.show()
```

Here is an image of what the graph shows: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter):

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
yfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)
```

Comment: where did you get ymft and md from?

Comment: thanks to @ubuntu for including matplotlib as md; ymft is a variable that I declare

Comment: @hankharrison I believe `yfmt` is short for _y axis format_

and `md` is short for _m = matplotlib_ and _d = dates_

Comment: where do i place that code at that it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: can you update the code to show where you included it?